# Having problems with Android Tabhost

Tags: android

I want to use Tabs in my custom Dialog.

Here's what I got:

`[project_settings.xml]`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:layout_height="450dip">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_dialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/a"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_dialog"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#DA5F6A"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/general"
                android:text="OK"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/resources"
                android:text="OK"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/variables"
                android:text="OK"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

`[ProjectSettings.java]`

```
public class ProjectSettingsWindow {
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.project_settings);

    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);


    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(""));

    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(""));

    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(""));

    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);


    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
    text.setText(msg);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
}
```

How do you make native, working tabs? Why doesn't it show up with XML only?
I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabWidget.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference` error when doing `tabhost.addTab()` even though there is such layout with such ID.

Here's how it looks like in XML:
[image]

Comment: tabHost.setup(); before you start adding?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup() tabHost prior to adding the tabs!

Try adding the following lines of code:

```
    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false); 
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
```

Comment: Ironically, I'm getting this error: https://i.gyazo.com/ae9d3e3f725e0188d686a2152f3a7134.png

Comment: hmmm. try again without the setContent lines, just try with setIndicators. I think it may not like your intents.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content`

Comment: LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

Comment: add the content back in and try the above.

Comment: `LocalActivityManager is deprecated.` `Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created.`

Comment: tabhost is not null: `D/tabhost.toString(): android.widget.TabHost{2590d183 VFE..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0065 app:id/tabhost}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136991/discussion-between-weary-adventurer-and-apollosoftware).